# What is the origin and meaning of the street names 一年坂, 二年坂 and 三年坂 in Higashiyama, Kyoto?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji, etymology, history

Obviously "1-year hill", etc., but what is the context of that?

And sometimes we see it spelled with 念 (nen) or 寧 (nei) instead of 年 (nen). Why is that, and which one would be correct?

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic for this site, but this link may help: https://www.westjr.co.jp/company/info/issue/bsignal/04_vol_95/feature02.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't understand the google translated version completely. Could you kindly TL;DR by any chance?